# i am stuck at one of the part T.T can anyone help me out?

Tags: python

I am creating a quiz... and i want to make sure that people can choose how many question they want to answer.. 
Write a program for an application that let the user host a quiz game. The application will have a collection of questions with short answers. The program should ask the user how many question they want for their game. It will then ask that many questions in random order. When the user types in an answer, it will check the answer against the correct answer and keep track of the number of questions they got right. It will never ask the same question twice. When all the questions have been asked, or the user has quit (by typing "quit" as an answer), the program will print the score and the total number of questions asked

```
from random import *   #random is a library. we need the randint function from it

    def Main() : 
        Questions = []  # list of all the  questions
        Answers = []    # list of all the answers 
        setup(Questions, Answers)

        while True :
            target = int(input("How many questions do you want to answer? more than 1 and less than 11 "))
            if target <= len(Questions) :
                break
            print("Sorry, I only have ", len(Questions), " in my databank")

      #  alternate version:
      #  target = int(input("How many questions do you want to answer? "))
      #  while target > len(Questions) :
      #  print("Sorry, I only have ", len(Questions), " in my databank")
      #  target = int(input("How many questions do you want to answer? "))
      # 

        score = 0
        numberAsked = 0
        while len(Questions) > 0 :
            qnNum = randint(0, len(Questions)-1)
            correct = askQuestion(Questions[qnNum], Answers[qnNum])
            numberAsked = numberAsked + 1
            if correct == "quit" :
                break
            elif correct :
                score=score+1
            del Questions[qnNum]
            del Answers[qnNum]
        reportScore(score, numberAsked)

    def reportScore(sc, numAsked) :
        print("Thanks for trying my quiz, Goodbye", sc, " questions right out of ", numAsked)


    #asks the user a question, and returns True or False depending on whether they answered correctly.
    # If the user answered with 'q', then it should return "quit"
    def askQuestion (question, correctAnswer):
        print(question)
        answer = input("your answer: ").lower()
        if answer == "quit" :
            return "quit"
        elif answer == correctAnswer.lower() :
            print("Well done, you got it right!")
            return True
        else :
            print("You got it wrong this time!. The correct answer is ", correctAnswer)
            return False

    #  Sets up the lists of questions
    def setup(Questions, Answers) : 
        Questions.append("The treaty of Waitangi was signed in 1901")
        Answers.append("FALSE")
        Questions.append("Aotearoa commonly means Land of the Long White Cloud")
        Answers.append("TRUE") 
        Questions.append("The Treaty of Waitangi was signed at Parliament")
        Answers.append("FALSE")
        Questions.append("The All Blacks are New Zealands top rugby team")
        Answers.append("TRUE")
        Questions.append("Queen Victoria was the reigning monarch of England at the time of the Treaty")
        Answers.append("TRUE")
        Questions.append("Phar Lap was a New Zealand born horse who won the Melbourne Cup")
        Answers.append("TRUE")
        Questions.append("God Save the King was New Zealand’s national anthem up to and including during WWII")
        Answers.append("TRUE")
        Questions.append("Denis Glover wrote the poem The Magpies")
        Answers.append("TRUE")
        Questions.append("Te Rauparaha is credited with intellectual property rights of Kamate!")
        Answers.append("FALSE")
        Questions.append("Kiri Te Kanawa is a Wellington-born opera singer")
        Answers.append("FALSE")

    Main()
```

Comment: I am creating a quiz... and i want to make sure that people can choose how many question they want to answer..this is the result i get from phyton shell.

Comment: How many questions do you want to answer? more than 1 and less than 11 1
Phar Lap was a New Zealand born horse who won the Melbourne Cup
your answer: 
You got it wrong this time!. The correct answer is  TRUE
Aotearoa commonly means Land of the Long White Cloud
your answer: 
You got it wrong this time!. The correct answer is  TRUE
The Treaty of Waitangi was signed at Parliament
your answer: 
You got it wrong this time!. The correct answer is  FALSE
Kiri Te Kanawa is a Wellington-born opera singer
your answer: 
You got it wrong this time!. The correct answer is  FALSE

Comment: @Dean: Don't put that as a comment! Add it to the question!

Comment: @BrenBarm my bad. I am a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is in your `while` loop - you aren't doing anything with `target`, which is what is supposed to be governing the number of questions asked. Without going too crazy on suggested modifications, try replacing the code around your `while` loop with this:

```
score = 0
numberAsked = 0
while numberAsked < target:
    qnNum = randint(0, len(Questions))
    correct = askQuestion(Questions[qnNum], Answers[qnNum])
    numberAsked = numberAsked + 1
    if correct == "quit" :
        break
    elif correct :
        score=score+1
    del Questions[qnNum]
    del Answers[qnNum]
```

This will loop while `numberAsked` is less than `target`. Your current issue is that your loop is governed by the length of the `Questions` list, which starts at 10 and decreases by 1 on each iteration. Therefore no matter what your `target` is, the loop will cycle through all of the questions.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python assesment.py", line 22, in <module>
    while target > 0:
NameError: name 'target' is not defined

Comment: @DeanOng Sorry, I meant replace the block of your code that starts with `score = 0` and ends with `del Answers[qnNum]` with this. To make it easier, in your code you can just replace `while len(Questions) > 0` with `while numAnswered < target`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python assesment.py", line 22, in <module>
    while target > 0:
NameError: name 'target' is not defined

Comment: @DeanOng Are you using your exact code that you posted here? Try replacing just the `while` statement with that is in the comment above.

Comment: i did    score = 0
    numberAsked = 0
    while numAnswered < target:
        qnNum = randint(0, len(Questions)-1)
        correct = askQuestion(Questions[qnNum], Answers[qnNum])
        numberAsked = numberAsked + 1
        if correct == "quit" :
            break
        elif correct :
            score=score+1
        del Questions[qnNum]
        del Answers[qnNum]
    reportScore(score, numberAsked)

Comment: @DeanOng And just to double-check, this is using the code you posted above? The entire script in the question?

Comment: yes i did used it but it came out error.

Comment: @DeanOng So your script as appears above works fine, but when you change the `while` statement to `while numAnswered < target:`, it fails? I copy/pasted your script and replaced that line and all seems to be working, so maybe there are some larger issues at play :)

Comment: can you post what you the coding here? coz i tried but came out error

Comment: @DeanOng Let's start from the beginning - can you get your script above to run without making any modifications?

Comment: @DeanOng No problem, happy it helped :) If all is good, you can click on the check mark under the 0 on the answer - that will 'accept' the answer and close the loop (if it didn't help, feel free to leave unchecked :) ).